# $_GET não recebe mais de uma variável

Tags: get

**Existe o seguinte link.**

```
<a style='color: bfbfbf; text-decoration: none;' href='autorizar.php?id=<?php echo $curso[0]['idCurso'].'&resp=s' ?>'>Sim</a>
```

Caso o sim foi clicado a variável resp = 's', caso o não for clicado, resp = 'n'

**Página autorizar**

```
<?php include '../AB/ab.php'; 

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $resp = $_GET['resp'];

    function autorizar($conexao, $id)
    {
        if($resp == 's')
        {
            $sqlAtrib = "UPDATE cursos SET exibirCurso='s' WHERE idCurso = $id";
            mysqli_query($conexao, $sqlAtrib);
            header("Location: curso2.php?curso=$id");
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'entrou no else';
        }
    }

        autorizar($conexao, $id);   
?>
```

No entanto só o $_GET['id'] está funcionando. E o erro retornado é que não foi possível encontrar a variável resp.

> Notice: Undefined variable: resp in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\Accipiter\Comercial\autorizar.php on line 8

Acredito que seja um erro **meu** de fácil resolução, mas não estou conseguindo resolver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema não é que o $_GET não recebe o valor, mas sim na sua função:

```
function autorizar($conexao, $id)
    {
        if($resp == 's')
        {
            $sqlAtrib = "UPDATE cursos SET exibirCurso='s' WHERE idCurso = $id";
            mysqli_query($conexao, $sqlAtrib);
            header("Location: curso2.php?curso=$id");
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'entrou no else';
        }
    }
```

Você não está declarando `$resp` em nenhum lugar, assim irá gerar a mensagem

> Undefined variable: resp

O que você precisa fazer é alterar a declaração da função acrescentando a variável:

```
function autorizar($conexao, $id, $resp)
```

E em sua chamada passar o novo parâmetro:

```
autorizar($conexao, $id,$resp);
```

Ou ainda, como você está criando a função no mesmo PHP que possui a variável `resp`, você pode usar a diretiva [global](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.scope.php):

```
function autorizar($conexao, $id){
    global $resp;
    ....
}
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo! Esqueci da passagem por parâmetro! Erro que ja não deveria ser cometido a muito tempo! haha vlw!